# Calling dialog.dismiss from another activity

Tags: android, kotlin, android-alertdialog

I'm trying to dismiss a custom dialog from another activity(MainActivity) which I extended to the BaseActivity class.

I tried to call the dialog.dismiss() method in the checkConnectivity() function as shown below:

```
   fun checkConnectivity() {
        val cm = getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
        val activeNetwork = cm.activeNetworkInfo
        val isConnected = activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting
        val internetErrorImg = resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.internet) as Drawable

        if (!isConnected) {
            alert()
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Connected.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            dialog.dismiss()
        }
    }
```

But it is returning an error that "lateinit property dialog has not been initialized".

So I tried to pass a boolean expression as shown below, if true it should show the dialog but if false it should dismiss the dialog.

```
    fun alert(image: Drawable, message: String, on: Boolean) {
        val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        val view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.alert_layout, null)
        builder.setView(view)
        builder.setCancelable(false)

        view.img.setImageDrawable(image)
        view.mssg.text = message
        dialog = builder.create()
        dialog.window?.requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
        dialog.window?.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT))

        if (on) {
            dialog.show()
        } else {
            dialog.dismiss()
        }
    }
```

And i called the function in the checkConnectivity() function like this:

```
        if (!isConnected) {
            alert(internetErrorImg,"Error connecting to the internet", true)
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Connected.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            alert(internetErrorImg, "null", false)
        }
```

But it isn't working nor showing any errors. 
How can I solve this?

This is the full code for BaseActivity

```
open class BaseActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    var TAG = this.toString()
    lateinit var dialog: AlertDialog

    fun checkConnectivity() {
        val cm = getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
        val activeNetwork = cm.activeNetworkInfo
        val isConnected = activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting
        val internetErrorImg = resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.internet) as Drawable

        if (!isConnected) {
            alert(
                internetErrorImg,
                "Error connecting to the internet, check connection and try again.", true
            )
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Connected.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            alert(internetErrorImg, "null", false)

        }
    }

    fun alert(image: Drawable, message: String, on: Boolean) {
        val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        val view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.alert_layout, null)
        builder.setView(view)
        builder.setCancelable(false)

        view.img.setImageDrawable(image)
        view.mssg.text = message
        dialog = builder.create()
        dialog.window?.requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
        dialog.window?.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT))

        if (on) {
            dialog.show()
        } else {
            dialog.dismiss()
        }
    }
```

This is my main activity where I'm extending to base activity class

```
class MainActivity : BaseActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        checkConnectivity()
    }
}
```

Comment: i copy and pasted your whole code and tried on the emulator. it showed connected when there was connection and it showed the error dialog when there was no connection. perhaps the erros is in the hardware?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use a nullable dialog instead of lateinit-

```kotlin
open class BaseActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    var TAG = this.toString()
    var dialog: AlertDialog? = null
```

And then modify the alert function like this-

```kotlin
    fun alert(image: Drawable, message: String, on: Boolean) {
        if (!on) {
            dialog?.dismiss()
            dialog = null
        }

        val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        val view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.alert_layout, null)
        builder.setView(view)
        builder.setCancelable(false)

        view.img.setImageDrawable(image)
        view.mssg.text = message
        dialog = builder.create()
        dialog?.window?.requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
        dialog?.window?.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT))
        dialog?.show()
    }
```